# Eclipse and pyddev: Error can't find Python32

Tags: python, eclipse

I cannot compile python in pydev in eclipse.  I get the following error:

"unable to make launch because launch configuration is not valid
Reason:
Interpreter: Python32 not found"

I am actually runnning Python26 and have configured Python26 as the interpreter in "Windows->Preferences"
I have deleted and replaced my copy of eclipse and this persists.  Any help would be appreciated.  I think that at one time I had Python32 running and then switched to Python26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably still have that selected in your project or launch configuration... You can try to delete your existing launch configurations (run > run configurations) so that they get recreated on a new run and if that's not it, take a look at your project properties > pydev - interpreter/grammar and see if an old interpreter was selected.